# Using Ajax with Rails 5 Beta

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-5

Recently, I wanted to update an app that I am working on to Rails 5. The app was behaving and correctly running in Rails 4.2.4. I went through the update process and everything seemed to be fine. I had to update/remove some gems in order to have the update complete as some gems would not work. Now, the only thing that is not working is the Ajax. I have tried using the responders gem. But that still did not render my Ajax call. With the responder gem, it says that it renders the corresponding find_group.js file. But does not execute any code in the file. .If anyone knows how to successfully use Ajax in Rails 5 Beta3. I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks

Relevant code:
users controller

```
def find_group 
    @group = Group.find(params[:id])  
           respond_to do |format|
              format.json
              format.js { render "users/find_group" }
            end
end
```

routes.rb

```
match '/users/find_group', to: "users#find_group", via: "post"
```

view with corresponding javascript code after ajax trigger

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'find_group',
   type: "post",
   data: {id: this.id},
   dataType: 'script'
});
```

find_group.js

```
$("#group").html("<%= escape_javascript (render("group")) %>");
```

In this file, none of the code is executed. I even threw in an alert to check. This is where everything comes to a hault.

Here is the console output in case anyone is interested

```
 Rendered users/find_group.js (0.5ms)
Completed 200 OK in 4827ms (Views: 8.6ms | ActiveRecord: 2.0ms)
```

Also, there was an error in the firebug console:

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
var errors = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, for anyone who has had this issue, you have to change the file extension from .js to .js.erb